# When I am trying to login in iframe in chrome and safari it is giving error but working properly in mozilla firefox

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, safari

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at  was set without the SameSite attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with SameSite=None and Secure. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at  and

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have embedded this site within a cross-site iframe, meaning that the cookies from the embedded site must specify the `SameSite=None` and `Secure` attributes to continue being sent.

See https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/ for more background.